# How can I get count in one window to another in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

In my code I'm getting the count of clicks in the second window and showing it in the first window which is the main window.How can I do this. What I tried below is not working

```
    C# code in second window

 public partial class Window1 : Window
    {
        int counter = 0;

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            counter++;
            hope.Text = counter.ToString();
        }
    }
```

```
    Xaml code in Main window
  <TextBlock x:Name="hope" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap"   FontWeight="Bold" Text="Attendees" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="23" Width="157"/>
```

Comment: use a view model.

Answer (score 2):

Your code isn't working because the TextBox `hope` is defined as a field in your main class and you're trying to reference it in your second class without specifying an instance of your *first* class. There's a few ways to get around this (you could expose a reference to `hope` as a public static variable), but you should definitely look into implementing MVVM. I recommend looking up a detailed tutorial on it so you can get the full story, but I'll try to explain the basics here.

When following MVVM (model-view-viewmodel), you partition your code into several discrete roles. XAML and any associated code-behind are considered part of the view role. The code samples in your question are part of the view as well. In general, you do *not* want the view to implement any logic outside of what is strictly necessary or else related directly to the UI. There are exceptions to this rule, but in general you should follow it.

The job of the view model is to facilitate communication between your model (data) and your view. For example, you could put your counter variable in a database, or package it into a serializable class and load it from a file. The viewmodel would access whatever model you choose via a public property, whose set and get functions would ensure the data is accessed correctly.

Finally, the view can access the counter by binding to the property on the viewmodel. Binding is really nice because it allows the view to *automatically update* when the property changes. However, to get this to work you'll need to have your viewmodel implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, which notifies your WPF component(s) that they need to display a different value.

Here's how it works:

1. The value on the viewmodel is changed.
2. The property that was modified raises a PropertyChanged event.
3. Any components bound to the property handle the event and update their value.

Finally, to change a property on the viewmodel from the view, you can use *commands*. Commands are implemented on the viewmodel and can be executed from the view. Commands can be used in place of events in many circumstances.

I wrote a simple counter program that demonstrates a few core MVVM principles. All it does is increment a number when you click on a button, similar to your sample code. It's in one window, but you can easily modify it to work with two different ones. I recommend trying to do that as an exercise so you can get a feel for how everything works.

If you're using Visual Studio, you can copy-paste all of this into a WPF project named "ExampleProject" and run it; I tested it and it works as expected.

XAML:

```xml
<Window x:Class="ExampleProject.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ExampleProject"
        xmlns:viewmodel="clr-namespace:ExampleProject.ViewModel"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">

    <!-- we reference our CounterViewModel class via XAML here. note that to access it, 
    we need to specify the namespace it's in by adding 
    xmlns:viewmodel="clr-namespace:ExampleProject.ViewModel"-->
    <Window.Resources>
        <viewmodel:CounterViewModel x:Key="Counter"></viewmodel:CounterViewModel>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <!-- here we bind to the Counter property in the viewmodel. we reference it in 
        XAML via the value assigned to x:Key (in this case, Counter). the value assigned
        to the "Source" parameter tells WPF where to look for properties. the value
        assigned to Path tells it which property to bind to.-->
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" 
                   Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource Counter}, Path=Counter}" 
                   FontSize="50" 
                   HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                   VerticalAlignment="Center"/>

        <Button Grid.Row="1" 
                Content="Press Me" 
                Command="{Binding Source={StaticResource Counter}, Path=Increment}"
                CommandParameter="{StaticResource Counter}"
                FontSize="60"></Button>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

ViewModel:

```cs
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Input;
using ExampleProject.Commands;
using ExampleProject.Model;

namespace ExampleProject.ViewModel
{
    //this is the viewmodel. note that it implements INotifyPropertyChanged.
    //you almost always want your viewmodel to do so.
    public class CounterViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        //invoke this whenever you change a property that your controls 
        //might be binding to
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        //this is the underlying data. including a reference to the model in
        //your viewmodel is one way to facilitate communication between the 
        //two, although there are other ways.
        private CounterModel model;

        //this is the most important part; your view will bind to this.
        public int Counter
        {
            get { return model.Counter; }
            set
            {
                model.Counter = value;
                PropertyChanged.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Counter"));
            }
        }

        //this is a function that will increment the counter and can be called
        //directly from XAML.
        public ICommand Increment { get; }

        //this constructor needs to be parameterless in our case, because
        //we will be creating an instance of this class from XAML.
        public CounterViewModel()
        {
            model = new CounterModel(0);
            Increment = new IncrementCommand();
        }
    }
}
```

Model:

```cs
namespace ExampleProject.Model
{
    //this is a simple model class. generally, you don't want to
    //implement any logic here; in pure MVVM the model just 
    //encapsulates raw data. 
    public class CounterModel
    {
        public int Counter;

        public CounterModel(int counterValue)
        {
            Counter = counterValue;
        }
    }
}
```

Increment command:

```cs
using System;
using System.Windows.Input;
using ExampleProject.ViewModel;

namespace ExampleProject.Commands
{
    public class IncrementCommand : ICommand
    {
        //necessary to implement because of ICommand but we're not currently using this
        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            //if this method returns false, the command won't be executed.
            return true;
        }

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            //parameter is passed in via XAML; it's always an instance of CounterViewModel
            //but i double-check what kind of object it is anyway.
            if (parameter is CounterViewModel viewModel)
            {
                viewModel.Counter++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that I didn't need to add anything to the code-behind. This isn't always possible, but it's often a good thing when you can manage it.

Comment: No problem. If you have any other questions or want clarifying information, feel free to ask.